# Hibernate HT_ Temporary Tables ON JOINED inheritance, Migration from Hibernate 3.4.0.GA To 5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to migrate an application from Hibernate 3.4.0.GA to Hibernate 5.1, and after complete the required changes on java code, when I deploy the application I'm watching how Hibernate is trying to **create HT_ tables** (global temporary), one for each **@Inheritance** annotated entity.

Searching on Google I've [found](http://in.relation.to/2005/07/20/multitable-bulk-operations/)  why the tables are being created.

But in my case we are not allow to change de database to add new tables.

My Inheritance model only has one level of Inheritance and its simple, [example](https://imagebin.ca/v/2b8fz1IrTnEt)

Does anyone knows any alternative representation for a hierarchical table structure that I can use to **avoid the HT_ tables creation**, or some Hibernate configuration to archive the same purpose?.

I can change the inheritance hierarchy on our entities or the Hibernate configuration. I can also asume an exception on deploy caused by the non creation of the tables if it´s non blocking for the rest of the deploy.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 1:** [New info from Hibernate official forum.](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043080)

**UPDATE 2:** [The Bug was fixed](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11262)

**UPDATE 3:** [A blog entry explaining different bulk Strategies related to the issue](https://in.relation.to/2017/02/01/non-temporary-table-bulk-id-strategies/)

Comment: The link in update 3 should be the solution of this issue

Comment: @rvheddeg updated !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As in update one on this [link](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043080) is more info from Hibernate official forum with a possible solution.

**UPDATE:** [Link with the solution](https://in.relation.to/2017/02/01/non-temporary-table-bulk-id-strategies/)

Comment: @snso i have updated the link, thanks for report the broken link

Comment: This is currently a link-only answer. Could you please include the important parts of the linked document in this post?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Oracle Database with Spring and not sure where to define property for hibernate can do the following.
Add

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy: org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy
```

In application.yml file from resource folder.

Comment: More than for oracle this is something exclusive for spring data layer, but nice