# Avoid Global Temporary Table creation in Hibernate 5.1.0

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-5.x

Hibernate creates global temporary tables names staring with **HT_** for bulk update and delete.

We are not supposed/allowed to create any table from application.

How do we switch off table global temporary creation for hibernate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate HT\_ Temporary Tables ON JOINED inheritance, Migration from Hibernate 3.4.0.GA To 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172996/hibernate-ht-temporary-tables-on-joined-inheritance-migration-from-hibernate-3)

Answer (score 1):

hibernate defined several options which you can choose depending on your database capabilities
1-InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy
2-InlineIdsSubSelectValueListBulkIdStrategy
3-InlineIdsOrClauseBulkIdStrategy
4-CteValuesListBulkIdStrategy

example to use these strategies

```
<property name="hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy"
          value="org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy"
/>
```

helpful link:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch

Comment: This is true for hibernate 5.2 onwards, but sadly this doesn't work with version 5.1, so you'll need to upgrade to a newer version.